# how to input data from Object into SimpleAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, simpleadapter

I want to fill out my `ListView` with some data and I use `SimpleAdapter`. But I think `SimpleAdapter` only works with `List<HashMap<String, String>>` and I've  `List<Object>` like follow codes:

What can I do? 
Is there any way?

```
List<DSarchive> programs = ...;
String[] from = new String[] {"name", "time", "day", "month"};
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.text3, R.id.text4};

SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), programs, R.layout.my_list_row, from, to);
//                                                        ^ how can I use this "programs" List???

lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I want to use adapter `List` in `MyObject`.

**MyObject** class:

```
public class MyObject{
    public ArrayList<String> links;
    public String name;
    public List<HashMap<String, String>> adapter;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using an `ArrayAdapter`

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
arrayList.add("temp1");
arrayList.add("temp2");
ListView listView = new ListView(getActivity());
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList));
```

**EDIT**

The `SimpleListAdapter` is not constrained to only use `Strings`. It does require a `String` key, but it can map to any object. For example, I used the following code to create a `ListView` that contains an Icon with two supporting `TextViews`. Hope this helps.

```
List<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();

Map<String, Object> dataMap = new HashMap<String, Object>(3);

dataMap.put("Item1", dataObject); //icon
dataMap.put("Item2", dataString);
dataMap.put("Item3", dataString2);
data.add(dataMap);

dataMap = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);
dataMap.put("Item1", dataObject); //icon
dataMap.put("Item2", dataString);
dataMap.put("Item3", dataString2);
data.add(dataMap);

SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), 
                                         (List<? extends Map<String, ?>>) data, 
                                         R.layout.layoutFile2, 
                                         new String[] {"Item1", "Item2", "Item3"} , 
                                         new int[] {R.id.item1, R.id.item2, R.id.item3}){

                                         //overload the getChildView or any other Override methods
                                         };
```

Comment: This way just input one data into each row, but i want input some data into each row.