# add image in multi listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

does anyone know how to add an image into multi listview? What I want is adding an image into `map1.put("Icon", "InsertImage");`

Code below is my java class

```
public class MultiList extends ListActivity {

    ListView lv; 
    SimpleAdapter sd;
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        lv=getListView();
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> alist=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        HashMap<String, String>map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();       
        map1.put("Class","Class 1");        
        map1.put("Icon", "InsertImage");     
        map1.put("Description", "Vehicles with 2 axles and 3 or 4 wheels excluding taxis");  
        alist.add(map1);

        sd=new SimpleAdapter(this,alist,R.layout.row,new String[]{"Class","Icon","Description"},new int[]{R.id.c1,R.id.i2,R.id.d3});
        lv.setAdapter(sd);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("Sravan", e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

in my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="4dip"
    android:paddingBottom="6dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/c1"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.44"
        android:text="text1"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/i2"
         android:layout_width="70dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
         android:layout_weight="0.7"
         android:text="text2"
         android:textSize="16sp" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/d3"
          android:layout_width="70dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
          android:layout_weight="0.7"
          android:text="text3"
          android:textSize="16sp" />

 </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the data type of what you mapping to. Instead of `HashMap<String, String>` try `HashMap<String, Object>`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748356/how-to-input-data-from-object-into-simpleadapter/17748698#17748698) for more assistance.

Comment: I'm not really understand on it and at last I had changed to another method to display my information. [link](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/)